# Does raising smithing over 100 do anything?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Semi-related:
[Is it possible to boost skills beyond 100 points?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35989/is-it-possible-to-boost-skills-beyond-100-points)

I bring this up because I just found the http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Notched_Pickaxe.

I did test this myself, and I didn't seem to see any difference in improving my armor.  Also note that the wikia page for the pickaxe specifically states that it can't be improved over 100.

Just want to verify with you guys, thanks!

EDIT

Thanks for the quick answers.  Not only is it possible, you can disenchant the Notched Pickaxe and get 10 extra smithing points by enchanting it onto 2 weapons we can be dual wielded.

Comment: The smithing bonus from the notched pickaxe enchantment does not stack.  You can only ever get +5.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, smithing over 100 has an affect on upgrading.  In [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/38744/9192) I raised smithing to 130 via two items.  That allowed me to increase the armor rating from 528 (@100 smithing) to 610 (@130 smithing).

Comment: appreciate the answer but going with Jon's since he was first.

Comment: @Killith np, you're the asker, you gotta do what you wanna do.

Comment: Yeah, you only got 1 vote on your awesome (and time consuming) answer for the linked question, so..

Answer (score 19):

Raising smithing above an effective value of 100 using items or potions does increase how much you can upgrade your items. Although there is no higher category than Legendary, you can still increase the numerical bonus.

You can test this by upgrading an item to Legendary without any gear or potions, then equipping items of +Smithing and drinking a potion, and upgrading the item on the workbench or grindstone (quickly, as the potion time limit does run down while you're smithing). You'll be able to upgrade a Legendary item even further.

Answer (score 1):

The armor cap is 569 with 4 pieces of armor. And it is increased by 25 for each piece of armor you remove since each armor has a hidden 25 point bonus and it of course is lowered if you have a mask on. So any more then 569 is pointless plain and simple. In that sense 100 smithing isn't really needed if you've already reached 569 with 4 pieces of armor.