# Can I fortify skills above 100?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to boost skills beyond 100 points?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35989/is-it-possible-to-boost-skills-beyond-100-points)

When my sneak is at 100, does a 25% bonus from the shrouded hood do anything?

I am currently trying to determine if keeping the hood around is useful or not.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes.**

Unlike in Oblivion, skills in Skyrim can be raised above 100.

This is probably most often used to fuel the Alchemy - Enchanting feedback loop, but it's also why the Fortify Restoration glitch is able to give you arbitrarily high stats.

Comment: Would you then answer this question please http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295975/what-is-the-math-formula-on-fortify-restoration-potion-improves-fortify-other-sk

Answer (score 0):

Considering the specific case of the sneak skill... hidden is hidden.  If you are never detected while you crawl around with 100% sneak skill, then another 25% is not useful.

Comment: You can certainly be seen with 100 Sneak.